# Read a xlsx/xls file - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, xlsx

Good day stackoverflow

I have this in the controller

```
def upload
 file_data = params[:data]

 #s = Roo::Excel.new(file_data.path)
 book = Spreadsheet.open file_data.path

 #--- continuous to read the file ---#
end
```

The problem is that it can read a .xls file on the Spreadsheet gem, but can't read a .xlsx file

In contrast the Roo gem can read both .xls/.xlsx files, but the param `file_data.path`don't work for the `Excel.new`function, shows a `"is not an Excel file"` error

I send the excel file in a file_field_tag in a form on the view, of course

Any ideas for the param `file_data.path` stackoverflow?

Answer (score 1):

When you use roo gem to read `xlsx` file, use `Excelx` class

```
   if File.extname(file_data.path) == ".xlsx"
    s = Roo::Excelx.new(file_data.path)
   else
    s = Roo::Excel.new(file_data.path)
   end
```

Comment: Not exactly the problem, actually is that when i upload a .xls file, in the Roo function, the `file_data.path`doesn't recognize it as a Excel file, but, with the same `file_data.path` code, it recognize it in the Spreadsheet function